# Sum and Annotate does not returns a decimal field Sum as a decimal

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, python-3.7

I am writing a query in which I want to Sum amount using annotate and Sum decimal field in a foreign key relationship.

The field is summed correctly but it returns the Sum field in integer instead of decimal. In the database the field is in decimal format.

The query is like:

`***models.objects.filter(SourceDeletedFlat=False).annotate(TotalAmount=Sum("RequestOrderList__PurchaseOrderAmount")).all()`

I do not want to use aggregate because I don't need overall column sum.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

> **models.objects.filter(SourceDeletedFlat=False).annotate(TotalAmount=Sum("RequestOrderList__PurchaseOrderAmount", output_field=DecimalField())).all()

Comment: I have mentioned that I can't use aggregate because I do not need full column sum. I only need sum of related primary key.